# Custom images in new Magento responsive e-mail header file

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, rwd

I have upgraded to Magento 1.9.1.0 and see that Magento has implemented a new way to include the header and footer of e-mails in transactional e-mails. Great!

I have succesfully included the header.phtml file with {{template config_path="design/email/header"}}. However, in header.phtml I want to add custom images. In the default file of Magento the logo is included by using {{var logo_url}}.

However, a command which I would normally use is not working:

Anyone got an idea on how to include custom images in the header of your transactional e-mails?

Comment: What command would you normally use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting image URLs is done with the following snippets:

```
{{skin url="path/to/file.jpg" _area="frontend"}}
```

or

```
{{media url='path/to/file.jpg'}}
```

More about this on this [blogpost](http://www.extensionhut.com/blog/magento-get-base-url-skin-url-media-url-js-url-store-url-and-current-url/)

Comment: Yes, thanks, that was already the snippet I was using but apparently magento was looking in the wrong directory / not my skin directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a bug in Magento, which sometimes prevents the correct images from showing up. I have found the answer [in this blogpost](http://addoa.com/blog/fixing-magento-transactional-email-theme-image-problems)

Apparently you sometimes have to apply both the package and theme in the link to the image:

```
{{skin url='images/email/logo.png' _area='frontend' _package='your-package' _theme='your-theme'}}
```